# Counting with IR sensors on the Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm to make a autonomous watercraft that collects debris (ping pong balls) as part of a group task. I thought it might be useful to track how much debris the watercraft captures. It's basically a catamaran design where the balls flow under it and into a net. An idea was to set up an IR sensor underneath that tracks how many balls flow in, the only problem being it would just add to the count if one was to flow out. We tossed around an idea of having two IR sensors that could tell the direction the balls were travelling i.e. if the first then second sensor were triggered it was going in and vice versa. There is only room for one ball wide underneath the watercraft. What might be the best way of programming the ball count on the Arduino using two sensors? Or how should the sensors be set up; one immediately after each other, a gap a ball wide in-between or even wider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted practice here is to ask more specific questions, however I do quite a bit of work with industrial automation as well as hobby programing so I will see if I can help you get started.

To determine the direction of something moving past 2 sensors you should place the sensors so that they are just wider than one ball.  You can tell what direction the object is going by seeing which sensor goes on first.

You will need to catch a couple of border line cases as well:  if a ball trigers one sensor then head back the way it came (waiting for the second sensor may not happen).  You can catch 2 balls coming in at once as both sensors will stay on.

Hope this gets you started.